# entry.get() shell/idle output issue

Tags: python, tkinter, python-idle

Okay so I'm trying to learn some GUI using tkinter following along this website's guide: https://realpython.com/python-gui-tkinter/#building-your-first-python-gui-application-with-tkinter
Depending on how I run the code it works using IDLE verse shell.

What happens in Idle is it is calling name long before anything is ever actually typed in the entry. which is why the output is  "" . Where in shell I can type something into the entry "john doe" and when I get to 'name' it has something it can output.

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(text = "Name")
entry = tk.Entry()

label.pack()
entry.pack()

name = entry.get()
name
```

Comment: You would need to do the `.get()` in response to some event that indicates that the user has finished entering data - the `command=` function of a Button is the typical place.

Comment: This question is extremely broad; please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The reason that your program worked in the shell is that the shell runs each line immediately, and prints any objects that return values. You should use `print(name)` to see the output when running it normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you would create a button that initiates the `.get` and start the mainloop for the window, like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

def print_entry(widget):
    name = widget.get()
    print(name)

window = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(text = "Name")
entry = tk.Entry()
button = tk.Button(text = "Get Entry",
                   command = lambda e = entry: print_entry(e))

label.pack()
entry.pack()
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```